# python: utilization of a list in a two level dict

Tags: python

How can I initialize a list in a two level dict in a pythonic way?

```
pos = defaultdict(dict)
pait = "2:N"
cars = ["bus","taxi"]
for x in cars:
    pos[x][pait]=[]
```

Comment: `pos = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's list and dictionary comprehensions come in handy for one-line initialization.

```
pos = {x: {"2:N": []} for x in ["bus", "taxi"]}
```